# EF Core - Problem adding data to many to many relationship

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

Before explaining my problem I just want to explain what I my goal with the code is.

My goal is to create a simple desktop application for creating recipes and a shopping list from selected recipes. So I want to be able to create Ingredients and Recipes separate from each other, and then add a quantity of ingredients (which I refer to as RecipeIngredients) to a recipe. The RecipeIngredient class contains information regarding the ingredient, but also quantity and measurement (e.g. kg).

With that said, my problem is that I am stuck trying to add RecipeIngredients to my Recipes.

I have set up a database using EF Core, and I am able to store Ingredients and Recipes separetly. But when I try to store a RecipeIngredient in a recipe, I get the following error: Unhandled exception. System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of the object.

I think my problem is that I do not completly understand what data I need to enter to create a object of RecipeIngredient, or how to link Recipe to a RecipeIngredient.

I have posted my code below, starting with main. Can any of you point me in the right direction? This is my first time using EF Core, and my first application that I try in c#, so I might have done something fundamentally wrong.

```
//Main
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SQLightRecipeRepository context = new SQLightRecipeRepository();
            var recipe = context.GetRecipe(1); // I already added recipes to the database, so they exist.
            var ingredient = context.GetIngredient(1); // Already added ingredients to the database, so they exist.
            recipe.RecipeIngredients.Add(new RecipeIngredient() { Ingredient = ingredient, Measurement = Measurement.kg, Quantity = 2 });
            context.Save();
        }

//Repository
 public class SQLightRecipeRepository : IRecipeRepository, IIngredientRepository, IRecipeIngredientRepository
    {
        private RecipeContext context = new RecipeContext();

        //Recipe
        public void DeleteRecipe(int recipeId)
        {
            Recipe recipe = context.Recipes.Find(recipeId);
            context.Recipes.Remove(recipe);
        }

        public Recipe GetRecipe(int recipeId)
        {
            return context.Recipes.Find(recipeId);
        }

        public IEnumerable<Recipe> GetRecipes()
        {
            return context.Recipes.ToList();
        }

        public void InsertRecipe(Recipe recipe)
        {
            context.Recipes.Add(recipe);
        }


        public void UpdateRecipe(Recipe recipe)
        {
            context.Entry(recipe).State = Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityState.Modified;
        }

        public IEnumerable<RecipeIngredient> GetAllIngredients(int recipeId)
        {
            return context.Recipes.Find(recipeId).RecipeIngredients.ToList();
        }


        //Ingredient operations
        public IEnumerable<Ingredient> GetIngredients()
        {
            return context.Ingredients.ToList();
        }


        public Ingredient GetIngredient(int ingredientId)
        {
            return context.Ingredients.Find(ingredientId);
        }

        public void InsertIngredient(Ingredient ingredient)
        {
            context.Ingredients.Add(ingredient);
        }

        public void DeleteIngredient(int ingredientId)
        {
            Ingredient ingredient = context.Ingredients.Find(ingredientId);
            context.Ingredients.Remove(ingredient);
        }

        public void UpdateIngredient(Ingredient ingredient)
        {
            context.Entry(ingredient).State = Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityState.Modified;
        }


        public void Save()
        {
            context.SaveChanges();
        }

        public IEnumerable<RecipeIngredient> GetRecipeIngredients(int recipeId)
        {
            var ingredients = context.RecipeIngredients.Where(r => r.RecipeId == recipeId);
            return ingredients.ToList();
        }

        public IEnumerable<RecipeIngredient> GetRecipeIngredients()
        {
            return context.RecipeIngredients;
        }

        public RecipeIngredient GetRecipeIngredient(int ingredientId, int recipeId)
        {
            return context.RecipeIngredients.Find(recipeId, ingredientId); 
        }

        public void InsertRecipeIngredient(RecipeIngredient recipeIngredient)
        {
            context.RecipeIngredients.Add(recipeIngredient);
        }

        public void DeleteRecipeIngredient(RecipeIngredient recipeIngredient)
        {
            context.RecipeIngredients.Remove(recipeIngredient);
        }

        public void UpdateRecipeIngredient(RecipeIngredient recipeIngredient)
        {
            context.Entry(recipeIngredient).State = Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityState.Modified;
        }

//DBContext (RecipeContext)
    public class RecipeContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Recipe> Recipes { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Ingredient> Ingredients { get; set; }
        
        public DbSet<RecipeIngredient> RecipeIngredients { get; set; }

        public string DbPath { get; }

        public RecipeContext()
        {
            var folder = Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData;
            var path = Environment.GetFolderPath(folder);
            DbPath = Path.Join(path, "recept.db");
        }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options) => options.UseSqlite($"Data source={DbPath}");

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Recipe>()
                .HasMany(r => r.Ingredient)
                .WithMany(r => r.Recipe)
                .UsingEntity<RecipeIngredient>(
                    j => j
                        .HasOne(ri => ri.Ingredient)
                        .WithMany(i => i.RecipeIngredients)
                        .HasForeignKey(ri => ri.IngredientId),
                    j => j
                        .HasOne(ri => ri.Recipe)
                        .WithMany(r => r.RecipeIngredients)
                        .HasForeignKey(ri => ri.RecipeId)
                );
        }

//Recipe, Ingredient and RecipeIngredient class
    public class Recipe
    {
        public int RecipeId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public List<RecipeIngredient> RecipeIngredients { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Ingredient> Ingredient { get; set; }

    }

    public class Ingredient
    {
        public int IngredientId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public List<RecipeIngredient> RecipeIngredients { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Recipe> Recipe { get; set; }

    }

    public class RecipeIngredient
    {
        public int IngredientId { get; set; }
        public Ingredient Ingredient { get; set; }
        public int RecipeId { get; set; }
        public Recipe Recipe { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
    }
```

Edit:
Added results from debugger:
[image: Debugger results]

Comment: Can you give more context "Unhandled exception. System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of the object." Does the error occur when inside InsertRecipe?

Is "context" null or is context.Recipes null?

Have you tried adding breakpoints to troubleshoot?

Comment: Hi @FredrikKarlsson I have added breakpoints, I took a screenshot of the results and put it in the post, hopefully that clarifies the error. As you can see, context.Recipes is not null.
Do I need to define more attributes in the recipeIngredients?

Comment: The null reference you get is right there in the debugger, recipe1.RecipeIngredients.

Comment: Yeah that's true, I added the recipeingredients in the wrong way. Thanks for helping out.

Answer (score 1):

Resolved the issue.

Added RecipeIngredients in the wrong way.

I added RecipeIngredients to the List in Recipes which caused the problem. It was resolved through creating a Recipeingredient object with reference to recipe and ingredient, and adding it to DBset RecipeIngredient instead.